# When does the difference of two random variables follow a symmetric distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, symmetry

**Setup**: Let $X_t$ and $Y_t$ denote two (possibly dependent) random variables with cumulative distribution functions (cdf) $F_X$ and $F_Y$. Assume the support of $F_X$ and $F_Y$ is $\mathbb{R}^+$. Let $Z_t = X_t - Y_t$, and let $F_Z$ denote the cdf of $Z_t$.

**Question**: What are the necessary conditions that must be placed on $F_X$ and $F_Y$ to ensure that $F_Z$ is symmetric, or approximately symmetric, around its first moment? Any references on this question would also be greatly appreciated. **Edit:** By symmetry, I mean that if $\mu = \mathbb{E} Z_t$, then $F_z(\mu - c) = 1 - F_z(\mu + c), \forall c$. Equivalently, if $f_Z$ denotes the probability distribution function, then $f_Z(\mu - c) = f_Z(\mu + c), \forall c$.

**Motivation**: One known result is that if $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are independent and identically distributed according to the exponential distribution, then $Z_t$ will follow the Laplace distribution, which is symmetric around its first moment (which is zero). I was wondering if there are some more general conditions under which $Z_t$ will follow a symmetric distribution.

Comment: Do you want to mean the symmetry of the pdf?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay I've adjusted the question to include a definition of the kind of symmetry I had in mind. If my meaning still isn't clear then please let me know and I'll have another go at editing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. (not necessarily exponential) then the distribution of $Z$ is symmetric. If $X$ and $Y$ are allowed to be dependent, the situation becomes horribly complicated.

Comment: Thanks, good to know +1. I'm guessing from your answer that the dependent scenario would probably need to be done on a case by case basis...

Comment: You can also have $X$ and $Y$ independent and each symmetrically distributed (though not necessarily identically).